# Odd glitch with opacity / bootstrap modal

Tags: css, google-chrome, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

As of few days ago users started reporting some odd graphics glitches with the modal backdrop. I've seen it on a couple of devices and haven't been able to get to the bottom of it - via inspector I can see that the Opacity is creating the glitch but seems very unusual. Also sometimes after switching tab and going to the original one the glitch is not there anymore.

Thoughts? has anyone encountered something like this before? (Please ignore the red strikethroughs)

[image]

Comment: The corresponding GitHub issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24233

Comment: Yeah seems that the issue needs to be reported to Chrome rather than bootstrap eh? Thanks for link

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same issue after Chrome updated to 61. To workaround this I temporarily swapped the opacity on modal backdrops for rgba(0,0,0,0.5) background. Note that rgba background is unsupported in IE8 so you'll either want to add a fallback or not utilize the workaround in that environment.

Answer (score 1):

I added style and it helped to avoid this bug

```
.modal-backdrop {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm seeing the same issue (black squares/artefacts) as well (since Chrome 61). I figure it's a rendering issue in Chrome.
As it is annoying to our customers we are looking for a workaround but other than removing all opacity styles we have no solution yet.

Comment: I've also opted to remove all opacity from modals for now

Comment: The issue is logged chromium buglist as well: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=770733

the suggested workaround for bootstrap modals is easy:
just change the background-clip property to border-box for class .modal-content 

`.modal-content {
    background-clip: border-box;   
}`

Answer (score 0):

Removing glitches / patches in bootstrap model fade

Check if there is border in model content and change it to none, it worked for me .

```
.modal-content {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: none;
}
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIqKr.jpg)